# Client ID not found for env: production paypal

Tags: magento2.3, payment, paypal-standard

I got an error on this block:

```
 Client ID not found for env: production paypal
```

On code:

```
        validate(client, props) {
        const env = props.env || config.env;

        if (!client[env]) {
            throw new Error(`Client ID not found for env: ${ env }`);
        }

        if (typeof client[env] === 'string') {
            if (client[env].match(/^(.)\1+$/)) {
                throw new Error(`Invalid client ID: ${ client[env] }`);
            }
        } else if (!ZalgoPromise.isPromise(client[env])) {
            throw new Error(`Expected client token to be either a string or a promise`);
        }
    },
```

Comment: Do you have In Context filled, and Merchant ID filled? I got this error on prod site when Merchant ID was empty

Comment: Any update on this? Have you found how can resolve

Comment: @PrinceYadav yea, restore some blocks from vendor helps for me.

Comment: Can  you  provide more details @AshenOne?

Comment: @DavidDuong that was a long time ago, so I fixed It by re-installing Magento, and move custom pieces to a new installation. I think someone from the team is broken the project files.